# How do I create an animated credits page?

Tags: iphone

I have a UITextView that has a lot of content (e.g. credit view), and I want to create an automatic scrolling view for it (something like the credits page for Firefox)
where it automatically scrolls the names

I have tried the following, but it is not smooth, and I also require it to happen automatically when user goes to that view

```
CGPoint scrollPoint = textView.contentOffset;

scrollPoint.y= scrollPoint.y+10;

[textView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Since `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, you can use its [`scrollRectToVisible:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/scrollRectToVisible:animated:) method to scroll with animation to any point you wish.

The [PageControl](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/) sample code demonstrates its use (although it's scrolling horizontally).

Answer (score 0):

So far I have done this, but still it is not smooth...

Any suggestions?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

[self run];

}

-(void)run{

    CGRect Frame1 = CGRectMake(5.0,5.0, 100.0,400.0);
    CGPoint scrollPoint = textView.contentOffset;

    scrollPoint.y= scrollPoint.y+100;

    [textView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

    [textView scrollRectToVisible:Frame1 animated:YES];
    NSTimer *time;
    time=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(run) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `scrollRectToVisible: animated:` nor `setContentOffset: animated:` have a property to control the *speed* or *duration* in which the animation occurs, so both will scroll fairly quickly to the destination point. They aren't good solutions for something like credits, which should scroll slowly.

Using `UIView animateWithDuration:` and then passing a `contentOffset` in the animation block is probably the best way to do this. However, there is a bug that clips text at the top if the length of the text is too long (even in iOS 10.0 SDK). There are two viable work-arounds for this bug discussed here:

[UIView.animateWithDuration on UITextfield's contentoffset: It clips the text (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910160/uiview-animatewithduration-on-uitextfields-contentoffset-it-clips-the-text-sw/39689725#39689725)